# Python Cross Module Variables

Tags: python, variables, module

I realize there are other threads addressing this problem but as I am fairly new to 'Classes' and have already constructed my class structure ... I would like to find a method that I can integrate into my code. I'm sure this will NOT be a difficult one to answer!

**First File: NameResult.py**

```
from NameAssign import *

NameList = NameWorks()
print(NameList.InputNames(NameVar))
```

**Second File: NameAssign.py**

```
class NameWorks:
    def __init__(self, NameVar = []):

        self.NameVar = NameVar

    def InputNames(self, NameVar):
        global NameVar
        NameVar = ['harry', 'betty', 'sam']
```

**Result:**

```
NameError: name 'NameVar' is not defined
```

All replies are much appreciated ...

Comment: If Ignacio's answer works for you, you should accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NameVar` is not defined in `NameAssign`; it only exists within `NameAssign.NameWorks.InputNames()` as a local variable. The easiest way to fix this is to define it in `NameAssign` at the global level.

**Edit:**

It turns out that this is what you want to do:

#### NameResult.py

```
import NameAssign

namelist = NameAssign.NameWorks(['harry', 'betty', 'sam'])
print namelist.InputNames()  # or print(...) for Py3k
```

#### NameAssign.py

```
class NameWorks(object):
  def __init__(self, names):
    self.names = names

  def InputNames(self):
    return self.names
```

Comment: great, where/how do I define it as global.

I've tried placing 'global NameVar' all over the place and it just returns: SyntaxError: name 'NameVar' is parameter and global

Comment: Not "as global", at the global level, i.e. at the same level as `NameWorks`.

Comment: This might be where the 'I'm new to classes' comes in. Could I have like an line or two of code as an example

Comment: This has nothing to do with classes. `NameVar = ['harry', 'betty', 'sam']`

Comment: oh ok. i see. I would like to record three names inside a list variable inside of class: NameWorks and import that list variable into NameResult.py

Comment: What I recommend you do is first figure out how you would do it with just functions. This will lead you a little closer to figuring out how to do it with classes.

Comment: Ok. I usually come here to get the example from which I learn. But not to worry, I can find these examples somewhere else. examples are a much faster way to learn than to 'figure out' as you put it. Thank you for your time

Comment: The problem is also that you haven't actually stated anywhere what you want this code to *do*, so it's difficult to give a complete answer.

Comment: i see. ok ... I would like the code to do this: Define a list with 3 names in it .. inside NameAssign.py Class NameWorks. I would then like to print this list using the NameResult module

Comment: would these 3 names be defined from nameresult? or from nameassign? and would there ever be more names, changing names?

Comment: ohh this is great ... but I do need the 3 names defined in NameAssign. thanks!! um yes more or less names

Comment: Then either assign the list to `self.names` in `NameWorks.__init__()` (and remove the parameter), or return the list directly in `NameWorks.InputNames()` (and remove `__init__()`).